# Пример по generics из Философии Java

Tags: java, generics

Приветствую всех! Читаю у Брюса Эккеля про дженерики, попался в качестве примера такой код:

```
 package net.mindview.util;
 import java.util.*;
 public class New {

 public static <K,V> Map<K,V> map() {
      return new HashMap<K,V>();
   }
 }

 public class LimitsOfInference {
     static void f(Map<Person, List<? extends Pet>> petPeople) {}

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          // f(New.map()); // Does not compile
     }
 }
```

И объяснение:

> Type inference doesn’t work for anything other than assignment. If you pass the result of a
>   method call such as New.map( ) as an argument to another method, the compiler will not
>   try to perform type inference. Instead it will treat the method call as though the return value
>   is assigned to a variable of type Object.

И тем не менее я воспроизвел этот код в IDE, он успешно скомпилировался и запустился. Это ошибка или информация в книге устарела? У меня jdk 8.

Comment: но в сообщении вроде не написано, что не будет компилироваться

Comment: Посмотрите закомментированную строку в коде. Я так понял, что автор имеет в виду ошибку компиляции.

Comment: https://ideone.com/I3kQUq

Comment: @ОлегМартынов вполне возможно дело действительно в версии. смотря какое издание книги вы читаете. вот в 4-ом издании рассматривались java 5 и 6. Начиная с 7 - запускается. так что скорее именно устарела инфа (1.6 - http://www.browxy.com/ - не запустится, 1.8 - https://ideone.com/I3kQUq - запускается)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Спасибо, видимо надо почитать что-то более актуальное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вся проблема в том, что у вас `Java 8`.

Укажите среде разработки, что нужно собрать это для `Java 6`, и вы увидите, что проект действительно не компилируется.

Все дело в *даймонд операторах*, которых в `Java 6` *еще не было*, соответсвенно, создавая `f(New.map())` считается, что это `map` с двумя `objecт`, а ожидается *параметризованный другими типами `Map`*.

Чтобы понять проблему, давайте возьмем пример попроще.

```
List <String> = new ArrayList <>();
```

Здесь после листа дженерик со стрингом, почему-то не отображается правильно... Это *вполне допустимо для `Java 8`*, поскольку `Java 8` видит в левой части параметризованный стрингами лист и сама дописывает в дженерик левой части тот же стринг в качестве параметра.

Однако, если запустить это на `Java 6`, то будет *ошибка компиляции*, потребуются явные параметры дженериков

```
`List <String> = new ArrayList <String>();`
```

То-же самое происходит в Вашем примере